# How do I install Expo CLI without getting stuck at deprecated warnings?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I am trying to install Expo CLI using `npm install -g expo-cli` but get stuck at this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[..................] \ fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com
```

I have also tried using `npm install -g yarn`

then `yarn global add expo-cli` .I have tried to be patient waiting for the installation to break through but it gets stuck there forever.please help

Answer (score 1):

I cannot remember exactly but the last time I resolved similar issue I had to do one of the following

1. Run the command in terminal (or IDE, if you use its terminal) with elevated privilege i.e. `sudo` or `run as administrator` (you did not mention which OS you are running on).  Most command with `-g` usually requires elevated permission because it has global effects
2. Kill any existing expo process
3. Kill any running simulator/emulator
4. Kill the terminal (or your IDE e.g. Visual Studio Code if you ran the process from its terminal)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, just wait for a while, I waited for 10mins.

```
[..................] \ fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com
```

It's not stuck actually, its very large file, so it's taking its time to download.

Comment: There is no way `request@2.88.2` can take 10 minutes to download. The unpacked size of the [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is 209kB.